# Service (LoadBalancer) port not working on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a `LoadBalancer` service on a `k8s` deployment on `aws` (made via `kops`).

Service definition is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <certificate_id>
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: ui-port
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: ui-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    els-pod: ui
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here is the respective deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ui-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        els-pod: ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <my_ecr_registry>/<my_image>:latest
        name: ui
        ports:
        - name: ui-port
          containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I know that `<my_image>` exposes port `80`.

I have also assigned an alias to the `ELB` that gets deployed, say. `my-k8s.mydomain.org`

Here is the issue:

- `https://my-k8s.mydomain.org` works just fine
- `http://my-k8s.mydomain.org` returns an empty page (when accessing behind a `squid` proxy, I get the `zero-sized reply` error message)

Why am I unable to access the service via port `80`?

**edit**: what I have just found is that the service annotation regarding the certificate, also **assigns it on port 80** on the ELB.

Could that be the issue?

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add the following annotation in the service definition:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
```